# How do I get multiple operating units access using ldap?

Tags: apache, ldap

I'm having a problem getting users within who are within our domain and in the appropriate active directory group(s) to have access to the repositories.  I am not very experienced with any of the security, nor using Subversion actively as a developer.

This is a critical issue to be resolved as our developers are more and more part of virtual teams requiring access to one centralized set of repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but if it's what I think it is, you may need to set the search base to something closer to the root of the tree.

Eg, if you have the base set to something like:

```
ou=Department1,dc=company,dc=com,o=internet
ou=Department1,o=companyname,c=us
```

Try stripping off the ou:

```
dc=company,dc=com,o=internet
o=companyname,c=us
```

You'll also need to make sure the search scope is `sub` not `one`.

The only problem comes up when the uid (or whatever you're using as the login) isn't unique across departments; I'm not sure how you'd handle that.  (I assume it's possible, as I know I log into some systems using 'realm/user', I just don't know how you'd map that to something for 'AuthLDAPURL', that you'd be using in this case)

For a breakdown of forming an AuthLDAPURL, see [Subversion with Apache and LDAP: Updated](http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2009/03/subversion-with-apache-and-ldap-updated.html) or [RFC2255](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2255.txt)